# Adding info of dictionary on Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dictionaries like this:

```
d1 = {'a':['v1','v2'],'b':['v2','v3']}
d2 = {'a':['v4','v5'],'b':['v4','v6']}
```

and a DataFrame `df` like this:

```
  id    x
  v1  Nan
  v2  Nan
  v3  Nan
  v4  Nan
  v5  Nan
  v6  Nan
```

and another DataFrame `another_df`like this:

```
id  name
 a  love
 b  hate
```

I need this as result:

```
df =
  id    x
  v1  love
  v2  love,hate
  v3  hate
  v4  love,hate
  v5  love
  v6  hate
```

I have some ideas on how to do it, like add new columns and then join them with commas, but I thought I should spare the fun of doing so 
Any ideas to do it properly without giving me headache?

If it works for only one dictionary I'll unify the rest of the dictionaries.

Comment: Could you close this question please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064822/return-dataframe-with-range-of-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf. `.items()` works only python3.x in python2.x you should use `.iteritems()` instead.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([(y_, x) for x, y in d1.items() for y_ in y])
d2 = pd.DataFrame([(y_, x) for x, y in d2.items() for y_ in y])
d12 = pd.concat([d1, d2])

df.merge(d12, left_on='id', right_on=0) \
  .merge(another_df, left_on=1, right_on='id')[['id_x', 'name']] \
  .groupby('id_x').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.values)) \
  .reset_index()

    name
id_x    
v1  love
v2  love, hate
v3  hate
v4  love, hate
v5  love
v6  hate
```

Comment: just, for some reason, I had to add .drop_duplicates() after the second merge

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution , I break done the steps

```
d1 = {'a':['v1','v2'],'b':['v2','v3']}
d2 = {'a':['v4','v5'],'b':['v4','v6']}
anotherdf=anotherdf.set_index('id')
df=pd.DataFrame([d1,d2]).T
df=df.unstack().apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
df['x']=df['level_1'].map(anotherdf['name'])
```

---

option 1 to `list`

```
df.groupby(0).x.apply(list).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'id'})
Out[296]: 
   id             x
0  v1        [love]
1  v2  [love, hate]
2  v3        [hate]
3  v4  [love, hate]
4  v5        [love]
5  v6        [hate]
```

---

option 2 `string`

```
df.groupby(0).x.apply(lambda x : ','.join(x)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'id'})
Out[295]: 
   id          x
0  v1       love
1  v2  love,hate
2  v3       hate
3  v4  love,hate
4  v5       love
5  v6       hate
```